# Why is my Moo object that inherits from a non-Moo class blessed into the parent's package for some modules?

Tags: perl, gobject-introspection, moo

I'm trying to create a Gtk3 application in Perl using [GObject Introspection](https://metacpan.org/pod/Glib::Object::Introspection) and [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo). There's a non-Moo class from Gtk, `Gtk::ApplicationWindow`, which I subclass through Moo using `extends 'Gtk::ApplicationWindow'`. The issue is that when an object of that subclass is created, it remains of the type of the parent class - i.e. `Gtk::ApplicationWindow`.

I tried the same thing by subclassing my own non-Moo based class instead, and the object created from this subclass is of the correct type. What could be the reason for this difference?

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

# Import the Gtk classes (non-Moo)
use Glib::Object::Introspection;
Glib::Object::Introspection->setup(basename => 'Gtk', version => '3.0', package => 'Gtk');
Glib::Object::Introspection->setup(basename => 'Gio', version => '2.0', package => 'Gio');

#################################################
{
    # A dummy non-Moo class
    package ClassNonMoo;
    sub new { bless {}, shift; }
}

{
    # Moo class extending the dummy class
    package ClassMoo;
    use Moo;

    extends 'ClassNonMoo';

    sub FOREIGNBUILDARGS {
        my ($class, %args) = @_;
        return ($args{app});
    }
}
#################################################

{
    # Moo class extending Gtk::ApplicationWindow
    package ClassMooGtkAppWin;
    use Moo;

    extends 'Gtk::ApplicationWindow';

    sub FOREIGNBUILDARGS {
        my ($class, %args) = @_;
        return ($args{app});
    }
}

#################################################

# Create objects of ClassMoo and ClassMooGtkAppWin
sub create_objects {
    my ($app) = @_;

    my $o1 = ClassMoo->new( app => $app );
    my $o2 = ClassMooGtkAppWin->new( app => $app );

    say "o1 = $o1\no2 = $o2";
    # Output:
    # o1 = ClassMoo=HASH(0x2f7bc50)
    # o2 = Gtk::ApplicationWindow=HASH(0x2f7bd40)
    #
    # Shouldn't o2 be of the type ClassMooGtkAppWin ?

    exit(0);
}

# We can create a GtkApplicationWindow only after creating a GtkApplication and
# running it. This code just ensures that create_object() is called once the
# application is 'active'.
my $app = Gtk::Application->new('org.test', 'flags-none');
$app->signal_connect(activate => sub { create_objects($app) });
$app->run();
```

Comment: Nice find. I tested with DateTime, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"new" constructors need to be written in a way to observe the caller's actual class (which works with subclassing), but they can also hard-code which class they create objects with.

Compare:

```
package MyClass;

# Considerate of subclassing
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    return bless {}, $class;
}

# Doesn't give a shit
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    return bless {};
}
```

Glib looks like it's an XS module wrapper around a C library, and it might hard code the class.

You could probably just try to re-bless (call bless again on the object that was constructed) the object into your actual subclass. Not sure exactly how that would work with Moo, but probably in the BUILD method.

You could also skip inheritance and use delegation instead. Create an attribute to hold the original Window object, and then delegate *all* methods to it, except your own in the subclass.

In Moose (not Moo), you can do this with a regex:
https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose#handles-ARRAY-HASH-REGEXP-ROLE-ROLETYPE-DUCKTYPE-CODE

Not sure how to do that nicely with Moo.

Comment: Yes this does appear to be the case and re-blessing in the `BUILD` sub makes things work fine and the subclass behaves like it should. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I can't find Gtk::ApplicationWindow to verify, but it probably does

```
sub new {
   my ($class) = @_;
   return bless({});
}
```

instead of

```
sub new {
   my ($class) = @_;
   return bless({}, $class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does look to be the case. The bindings for Gtk::ApplicationWindow are automatically generated at runtime (or compile time?) by Glib::Object::Introspection and it's probably not blessing the hashref correctly.

Comment: Ah, I get what the module does now. Unfortunately, fixing the module would not be trivial, at least not to someone not familiar with its inner workings.